# Strange inheritance modification

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, abstraction

I'm a .NET developer and know pretty much about OOP.
However, recently I noticed one interesting fact.

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` derives from 
`System.Data.Common.DbCommand`. The latter implements `System.IDbCommand`.
`System.IDbCommand` exposes the property `Connection` which an instance of `IDbConnection`.
In `DbCommand` However this property returns `DbConnection` type. And finally the same property in `SqlCommand` is of type `SqlConnection`

I've tried to perform the same however it gave a compile time error. How was this achieved in above example and how can I recreate the same pattern?

My code (not compiling):

```
public interface IFoo { }
public interface IBar 
{
   IFoo TheFoo();
}

public abstract class AbsFoo : IFoo { }
public abstract class AbsBar : IBar 
{
    public abstract AbsFoo TheFoo();
}

public class ConcreteFoo : AbsFoo { }
public class ConcreteBar : AbsBar { }
```

Comment: You need to use both Jason's **and** Richard's answers to do what `SqlCommand` does. Both answers are two parts of the whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) is the name of the game here. Try this:

```
public abstract class AbsBar : IBar {
    IFoo IFoo.TheFoo() { return this.TheFoo(); }
    public abstract AbsFoo TheFoo();
}
```

Here's a good guide on [implicit vs. explicit implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx).

Comment: I'm marking `IBar.TheFoo()` as abstract and the second method as public abstract but it still gives me a compiler error

Comment: Sorry, I see it is necessary to implement the explicitely declared method. I can't just make it abstract.

Comment: This is not correct, and doesn't even compile.  Implict vs. explict implementation does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Jason What using directives? Your code doesn't compile. And the reason why SqlCommand can have Connection return a different type is than DbCommand is because Connection is simply a public property.  You compilation error is "The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item".  The documentation is wrong, look in Object Browser and you'll see the signature for DbCommand.Connection is public DbConnection Connection { get; set; }, and the signature for SqlCommand.Connection is public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }.  I'm looking right at it.

Comment: In addition if you look at SqlCommand in Object Browser, and turn on show Inherited Members you'll see two Connection properties, one that returns DbConnection and the other SqlConnection, but the one returning DbConnection is hiding from normal access.

Comment: It is hiding because of explicit interface implementation! (And sorry for the compilation error; I cut-and-paste prematurely but please forgive me.) The documentation is not wrong.

Comment: @Jason - You only answered half the question here. Richard's answer was the second half. The OP needs to use both explicit interface implementation **and** method shadowing to acheive what `SqlCommand` does.

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that I think **Richard** was a little hard done by - his answer is just as good as **Jason**'s in that they both only answered half of the question. **Put them both together and you have the full answer.**

To make this work with `IDbCommand`, `DbCommand` & `SqlCommand` there has to be an explicit implementation of `IDbCommand` in `DbCommand` (**Jason's answer**) and public method shadowing in `SqlCommand` (**Richard's answer**).

I'll give the full "Foo/Bar" example.

Start with these interfaces:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IBar GetBar();
}

public interface IBar { }
```

Next `Foo` must provide an explicit implementation of `IFoo` in order to return `Bar`, not `IBar`, from its own `GetBar` method:

```
public abstract class Foo : IFoo
{
    IBar IFoo.GetBar()
    {
        return this.GetBar();
    }

    public Bar GetBar()
    {
        return this.GetBarInner();
    }

    protected abstract Bar GetBarInner();
}

public abstract class Bar : IBar { }
```

And finally a `SomeFoo` class must shadow `GetBar` to be able to return a `SomeFoo` instance:

```
public class SomeFoo : Foo
{
    public new SomeBar GetBar()
    {
        return new SomeBar();
    }

    protected override Bar GetBarInner()
    {
        return this.GetBar();
    }
}

public class SomeBar : Bar { }
```

I think the only information that Richard is that my adding the `new` keyword to the shadowed method you get rid of the compiler error.

Comment: Hooray for 3rd party observations.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Connection in DbCommand and SqlCommand are both just public methods.  There would be a compiler warning, but it's allowed.  Your code should be more like this to work like SqlCommand/DbCommand:

```
    public interface IFoo { }
public abstract class AbsBaseBar
{
    public IFoo TheFoo() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
public class AbsFoo : IFoo { }
public class AbsBar : AbsBaseBar
{
    public AbsFoo TheFoo() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class ConcreteFoo : AbsFoo { }
public class ConcreteBar : AbsBar { }
```

Comment: I think you were a little hard done by here Richard - you did answer **half** of the question quite correctly. And Jason missed your half entirely. I gave you an upvote to get rid of the negative.